# What is a Top-Tier™ word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is inspired by the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Top-Tier™ word.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

| A Top-Tier™ word | Not a Top-Tier™ word |
| --- | --- |
| Officer | Deputy |
| Smell | Odor |
| Pioneer | Colonizer |
| Nut | Maniac |
| Quizzically | Curiously |
| Puzzled | Confused |
| Break | Shattered |

Why are these called Top-Tier™ words?

CSV version:

```
A Top-Tier™ word, not a Top-Tier™ word
Officer,Deputy
Smell,Odor
Pioneer,Colonizer
Nut,Maniac
Quizzically,Curiously
Puzzled,Confused
Break,Shattered
```

Comment: I  know with some criteria, it can be difficult to generate words that fit the category, but if you can provide more than 5 examples, it will make it much less likely that someone will find an incorrect answer that fits with your examples.  (The more data, the less chance of a false positive answer.)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I added two more terms. I'll likely add more if nobody finds the answer soon.

Comment: @Bass No, sorry. I copied + pasted this from another Word/Phrase puzzle, and it looks like I missed that.

Comment: Does the solution require in-depth knowledge of the English language, especially the nuances of these words? (Just wondering, as I am non-native)

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy No. In fact, probably anyone could solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Top-Tier™ word is a word …

> … the length of which is a prime number.

as shown with the Top-Tier™ words:

> Officer (7)
>  Smell (5)
>  Pioneer (7)
>  Nut (3)
>  Quizzically (11)
>  Puzzled (7)
>  Break (5)

and the non-Top-Tier™ words:

> Deputy (6)
>  Odor (4)
>  Colonizer (9)
>  Maniac (6)
>  Curiously (9)
>  Confused (8)
>  Shattered (9)